# Backbone, collection models can't be accessed in function that fires from router Vent

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous, requirejs, fetch, amd

So my issue is that the collection in my function that is being fired from my router vent/event aggregator does not have access to my main collection's fetched models.

My guess is that it's an asynchronous call issue, but how can I make it so the vented function call WAITS until the collection/models are fetched before executing? Or is that even my issue?

Here's is my  relevant code. I'm using require.js and backbone to create a modular AMD app. Thank you so much in advance:

main.js

```
require(['views/app'], function (AppView) {
window.App = {
    Vent : _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
};
new AppView();
```

router.js

```
    define([
        'backbone',
    ], function(Backbone){

    var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      'levelone/:id':'showWork'
    },

    showWork: function (index){
      App.Vent.trigger('addressChange', {
        index: index
      });
   }
});
   return MainRouter;
});
```

App.js

```
define([
'backbone',
'views/levelone/LevelOneView',
'views/leveltwo/LevelTwoView',
'views/static/StaticView',
'router'
],
function(Backbone, LevelOneView, LevelTwoView, StaticView, MainRouter){
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),

    events: {
               ...
    },
    initialize: function(){                 
        new LevelOneView();
        App.router = new MainRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    },
   .............
```

LevelOneView.js

```
initialize:function() {
    this.getCollection();   
    this.domSetup();

    App.Vent.on('addressChange', this.addressChange, this);
},
getCollection : function(){
    var self = this;
    onDataHandler = function(collection) {
        self.LevelTwoCollectionGrab();
    };

    this.collection = new LevelOneCollection([]);
    this.collection.fetch({ success : onDataHandler, dataType: "jsonp" });
},
// We grab a Level Two Collection here so we can take the ids from it and add them to our Level One collection.
// This is necessary so we can create links between the two levels.
LevelTwoCollectionGrab: function(){
    var self = this;

    this.leveltwocollection = new LevelTwoCollectionBase([]);

    onDataHandler = function(collection){
        self.render();
        self.$el.animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 1200);
        self.renderLevelTwoIds();
        self.setLevelTwoids();
        self.attachLevelTwoLink();
    }
    this.leveltwocollection.fetch({success : onDataHandler, dataType: "jsonp"});
},
renderLevelTwoIds: function(){
    return this;
},
render: function(){
    var pathname = window.location.hash;

    this.setModelId(this.collection.models);
    this.addPositionsToIndex();
    this.determineModels();
    this.attachLevelTwoLink();
    ....... 
},      

addressChange: function(opts){

console.log(this.collection.models)
//returns a big fat empty array. WHY?!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery Promises returned by `fetch` to help you know when both collections are fetched.

```
initialize:function() {
    this.getCollection();   
    this.domSetup();

    App.Vent.on('addressChange', this.addressChange, this);
},
getCollection : function(){
    var self = this;

    console.log('should be first');

    this.collection = new LevelOneCollection([]);
    this.fetchingLevelOne = this.collection.fetch({ dataType: "jsonp" });
    this.fetchingLevelTwo = this.leveltwocollection.fetch({ dataType: "jsonp"});

    // wait for both collections to be done fetching.
    // this one will always be called before the one in addressChange
    $.when(this.fetchingCollectionOne, this.fetchingCollectionTwo).done(function(){
        console.log('should be second');
        self.render();
        self.$el.animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 1200);
        self.renderLevelTwoIds();
        self.setLevelTwoids();
        self.attachLevelTwoLink();
    });
},

renderLevelTwoIds: function(){
    return this;
},
render: function(){
    var pathname = window.location.hash;

    this.setModelId(this.collection.models);
    this.addPositionsToIndex();
    this.determineModels();
    this.attachLevelTwoLink();
    ....... 
},      

addressChange: function(opts){
    var self = this;

    // wait for both collections to be done fetching.
    // this one will always be called AFTER the one in getCollection
    $.when(this.fetchingCollectionOne, this.fetchingCollectionTwo).done(function(){
        console.log('should be third');
        console.log(self.collection.models);
    });
}
```

A nice thing about this, if the user is very very fast at typing in the address bar, and several `addressChange` calls are made, they will all wait until the collections are fetched and will execute in the proper order.

Comment: Hmmmmm, that appears to be a great start. If I navigate to the url from within the app, then things work as they should and your method is wonderful.

HOWEVER, if I navigate to that url from outside the page, then the array that is returned is still big and fat and empty and making me angry. Any idea why that is happening? It must be because large parts of the rest of my view are not firing, correct?

Comment: @CameronStrandberg After reviewing my code, I think I found a problem.  When the app starts up, you could get to the `when` code before the `this.fetchingCollectionTwo` is set.  And when you pass undefined to `when` it treats it like a resolved promise.  It seems like you don't need to wait until the first collection is fetched to fetch the second, unless maybe you left out some code... If not, try the updated code, which guarantees that both promises will be set before any `when` call.

Comment: Nope, sorry my friend, this does not work either. The array is still empty.

It's definitely an async issue. If I place a timeout on the console.log over the address change function, I get the models in my log. Without that, the addressChange function is simply firing before the models have been retrieved. I understand the concept of waiting for fetch to complete on success but everything in the trigger by vent addressChange function does not seem to know what it's waiting on.

Comment: Hmm, very strange. You can put some breakpoints in dev tools and see what order things get hit. But in that code, `getCollection` is called  before hooking up `addressChange` event. And you are calling `history.start()` after all that, so those deferreds should both be there when `addressChange` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. Basically, I'm now calling the function inside of $.when function--

Like so:

```
    $.when(this.collection.fetch(), this.leveltwocollection.fetch()).done(function(){
        $.when(self.render()).done(function(){
            _.each(self.collection.models, function(model){
                var wpid = model.get('id'),
                    bbid = model.id;
                if (wpid == index){
                    window.App.InfoPos.pos5 = bbid;
                    var modelinfo = model.toJSON();
                    $('.box5').empty();
                    $('.box5').html(tmplOne(modelinfo));
                    self.$el.animate({
                        'opacity': 1
                    }, 1200);
                }
            });             
        });
    });
```

The function launches from inside the when call and then waits until completed before executing anything in the done function. Works now! Thanks for the help all, especially you Paul.